# ViewHolder class is not recognizing

Tags: android

I was trying to create a object of ViewHolder in my class which is extends BaseAdapter class but it is not recognizing the ViewHolder class can anyone please solve my problem

What is the alternative class for ViewHolder

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you have to create a class that extends the `ViewHolder` yourself.

Comment: we can't solve a problem without some code. Check: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Create your Own ViewHolder class:

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
}
```

Comment: android studio is recognizing RecyclerView.ViewHolder